# Simple redirect appending the REQUEST_URI in URL

Tags: .htaccess, isapi-redirect

I am trying to redirect if the `REQUEST_URI` contains `/register/affiliate/32`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /register/affiliate/32
RewriteRule (.*)  https://affiliate.example.com [R=301,L]
```

It is working fine but it is also including the `REQUEST_URI` in redirected URL how may I prevent it, that the URI is not included in the redirected URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/register/affiliate/32
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://affiliate.example.com [R=301,L]
```